# LiveData updates executes code when it shouldnt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

My app is observing multiple livedata objects from my viewmodel and is relying on that data being updated to display the matching data for each screen but it is executing a certain part of my code twice when navigating from one fragment to another, which I dont want.

It starts in this fragment where when the user clicks the nextscreen button, a certain livedata object gets updated and the app navigates to another screen:

```
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"


class MainScreenFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentMainScreenBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var actionBar: ActionBar
    private val viewModel : MainScreenViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)


        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentMainScreenBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        actionBar = (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!
        actionBar.show()
        val nextScreenButton = binding.nextScreenButton
        nextScreenButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (viewModel.locations.value?.size != 0){
                viewModel.getSavedLocationWeather()
                val action = MainScreenFragmentDirections.actionNavHomeToSavedLocationFragment()
                findNavController().navigate(action)
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireContext(),
                    getString(R.string.none_saved_warning),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun observeImageData(city: String, weather: String) {
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                viewModel.loadImage(city, weather)
                    .collect { imageDto ->
                        imageDto!!.urls.regular.let { imageUrl ->
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                viewModel.setImageLiveData(imageDto)
                                viewModel.loadImageIntoImageView(
                                    imageUrl, binding.backgroundImageView
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    showToast("Error loading image")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private suspend fun showToast(message: String) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.currentWeather.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { weatherData ->
                    weatherData.weather.currentWeather?.let { currentWeather ->
                        val city = weatherData.location.cityName
                        val weather =
                            weatherData.weather.currentWeather?.weatherConditions?.get(0)?.mainDescription
                        observeImageData(city, weather!!)
                        binding.mainTempDisplay.text =
                            getString(R.string.center_temp, currentWeather.temperature)
                        //            Current hour values
                        binding.centerTempRow.leftWeather.text =
                            currentWeather.weatherConditions[0].mainDescription
                        binding.centerTempRow.leftTemp.text = currentWeather.temperature.toString()
                        binding.centerTempRow.leftTime.text =
                            weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(0)?.timestamp
                        //            Next hour values
                        binding.centerTempRow.centerWeather.text =
                            weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(1)?.weatherConditions?.get(0)?.mainDescription
                        binding.centerTempRow.centerTemp.text =
                            weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(1)?.temperature.toString()
                        binding.centerTempRow.centerTime.text =
                            weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(1)?.timestamp.toString()
                        //            2 hours from now values
                        binding.centerTempRow.rightWeather.text =
                            weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(2)?.weatherConditions?.get(0)?.mainDescription
                        binding.centerTempRow.rightTemp.text =
                            weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(2)?.temperature.toString()
                        binding.centerTempRow.rightTime.text =
                            weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(2)?.timestamp.toString()
                        binding.locationDisplay.text =
                            getString(R.string.center_location_text, weatherData.location.cityName, weatherData.location.country)
                        binding.mainWeatherWidget.feelsLikeTv.text =
                            getString(R.string.feels_like, currentWeather.feelsLike)
                        binding.mainWeatherWidget.windSpeedTv.text =
                            getString(R.string.wind_speed, currentWeather.windSpeed)
                        binding.mainWeatherWidget.visibilityValue.text =
                            getString(R.string.visibility, currentWeather.visibility)
                        binding.mainWeatherWidget.chanceOfRainTv.text =
                            getString(
                                R.string.chance_of_rain,
                                weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(0)?.chanceOfRain
                            )
                        binding.mainWeatherWidget.uvIndexTv.text =
                            getString(R.string.uv_index_value, currentWeather.uvi)
                        binding.mainWeatherWidget.humidtyTv.text =
                            getString(
                                R.string.humidity, currentWeather.humidity
                            )
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        viewModel.currentWeather.removeObservers(viewLifecycleOwner)
        _binding = null
    }
```

The fragment it navigates to is this one:

```
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"


class SavedLocationFragment : Fragment() {
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private var _binding: FragmentSavedLocationBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val viewModel: MainScreenViewModel by activityViewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentSavedLocationBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        return binding.root
    }
    private fun observeImageData(city: String, weather: String) {
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, city)
                viewModel.loadImage(city, weather)
                    .collect { imageDto ->
                        imageDto!!.urls.regular.let { imageUrl ->
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                viewModel.setImageLiveData(imageDto)
                                viewModel.loadImageIntoImageView(
                                    imageUrl, binding.backgroundImageView
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    showToast("Error loading image")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private suspend fun showToast(message: String) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val mediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<Pair<List<LocationDto>, Int>>()
            mediatorLiveData.addSource(viewModel.locations) { locations ->
                val locationIndex = viewModel.locationIndex.value
                if (locationIndex != null) {
                    mediatorLiveData.value = Pair(locations, locationIndex)
                }
            }

            mediatorLiveData.addSource(viewModel.locationIndex) { locationIndex ->
                val locations = viewModel.locations.value
                if (locations != null) {
                    mediatorLiveData.value = Pair(locations, locationIndex)
                }
            }
            mediatorLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { (locations, locationIndex) ->
                Log.d(TAG, locationIndex.toString())
                Log.d(TAG, locations.size.toString())
                Log.d(TAG, locations[locationIndex].cityName)
                val endOfList = locationIndex >= locations.size - 1
                val startOfList = (locationIndex == 0 && locations.isNotEmpty())
                Log.d(TAG, endOfList.toString())
                Log.d(TAG, startOfList.toString())

                if (endOfList){
                    binding.nextScreenButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                }
                else {
                    binding.nextScreenButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.nextScreenButton.setOnClickListener {
                        viewModel.getSavedLocationWeather()
                        viewModel.incrementIndex()
                    }
                }

                if (startOfList){
                    binding.prevScreenButton.visibility =  View.INVISIBLE
                }
                else {
                    binding.prevScreenButton.visibility =  View.VISIBLE
                    binding.prevScreenButton.setOnClickListener {
                        viewModel.getSavedLocationWeather()
                        viewModel.decrementIndex()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.savedWeather.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { weatherData ->
                weatherData.weather.currentWeather?.let { currentWeather ->
                    val city = weatherData.location.cityName
                    val weather =
                        weatherData.weather.currentWeather?.weatherConditions?.get(0)?.mainDescription
                    observeImageData(city, weather!!)
                    binding.mainTempDisplay.text =
                        getString(R.string.center_temp, currentWeather.temperature)
                    //            Current hour values
                    binding.centerTempRow.leftWeather.text =
                        currentWeather.weatherConditions[0].mainDescription
                    binding.centerTempRow.leftTemp.text = currentWeather.temperature.toString()
                    binding.centerTempRow.leftTime.text =
                        weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(0)?.timestamp
                    //            Next hour values
                    binding.centerTempRow.centerWeather.text =
                        weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(1)?.weatherConditions?.get(0)?.mainDescription
                    binding.centerTempRow.centerTemp.text =
                        weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(1)?.temperature.toString()
                    binding.centerTempRow.centerTime.text =
                        weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(1)?.timestamp.toString()
                    //            2 hours from now values
                    binding.centerTempRow.rightWeather.text =
                        weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(2)?.weatherConditions?.get(0)?.mainDescription
                    binding.centerTempRow.rightTemp.text =
                        weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(2)?.temperature.toString()
                    binding.centerTempRow.rightTime.text =
                        weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(2)?.timestamp.toString()
                    binding.locationDisplay.text =
                        getString(R.string.center_location_text, weatherData.location.cityName, weatherData.location.country)
                    binding.mainWeatherWidget.feelsLikeTv.text =
                        getString(R.string.feels_like, currentWeather.feelsLike)
                    binding.mainWeatherWidget.windSpeedTv.text =
                        getString(R.string.wind_speed, currentWeather.windSpeed)
                    binding.mainWeatherWidget.visibilityValue.text =
                        getString(R.string.visibility, currentWeather.visibility)

                    binding.mainWeatherWidget.chanceOfRainTv.text =
                        getString(
                            R.string.chance_of_rain,
                            weatherData.weather.hourlyWeather?.get(0)?.chanceOfRain
                        )
                    binding.mainWeatherWidget.uvIndexTv.text =
                        getString(R.string.uv_index_value, currentWeather.uvi)
                    binding.mainWeatherWidget.humidtyTv.text =
                        getString(
                            R.string.humidity, currentWeather.humidity
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
```

When MainScreenFragment navigates to SavedLocationFragment, this function gets called in the viewmodel:

```
  fun getSavedLocationWeather() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                locationRepository.getLocations().distinctUntilChanged().collect { locations ->
                    if (locationIndex.value != null && locations.isNotEmpty()) {
                        try {
                            weatherRepository.getWeather(locations[locationIndex.value!!].cityName).distinctUntilChanged()
                                .collect { data ->
                                    try {
                                        val weatherData = convertWeatherDtoToWeatherModel(data.weather)
                                        _savedWeather.value = LocationWeatherModel(
                                            location = LocationModel(
                                                data.location.cityName,
                                                data.location.country
                                            ),
                                            weather = weatherData
                                        )
                                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                                        handleError(e)
                                    }
                                }
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            handleError(e)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                handleError(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

it uses these livedata objects:

```
  private var _locationIndex = MutableLiveData(0)

  val locationIndex: LiveData<Int> get() = _locationIndex

  private var _locations = MutableLiveData<List<LocationDto>>()
  val locations: LiveData<List<LocationDto>> get() = _locations
```

_locations gets initialized in the viewmodels init {} block.

MainscreenFragment observes this livedata object:

```
  private val _currentWeather = MutableLiveData<LocationWeatherModel>()
    val currentWeather: LiveData<LocationWeatherModel> get() = _currentWeather
```

and SavedLocationFragment observes this one:

```
 private val _savedWeather = MutableLiveData<LocationWeatherModel>()
    val savedWeather: LiveData<LocationWeatherModel> get() = _savedWeather
```

So when the user navigates from MainscreenFragment to SavedLocationFragment and getSavedLocationWeather gets called in the viewmodel while the next Fragment gets loaded _savedWeather gets updated and savedWeather, locationIndex, and locations get observed by the new fragment. The user can call getSavedLocationWeather and update the data for SavedLocationFragment while in the fragment and when that happens the code does not get executed twice but when the user calls getSavedLocationWeather and navigates from MainscreenFragment  to SavedLocationFragment all the code in this block gets executed twice:

```
 val mediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<Pair<List<LocationDto>, Int>>()
            mediatorLiveData.addSource(viewModel.locations) { locations ->
                val locationIndex = viewModel.locationIndex.value
                if (locationIndex != null) {
                    mediatorLiveData.value = Pair(locations, locationIndex)
                }
            }

            mediatorLiveData.addSource(viewModel.locationIndex) { locationIndex ->
                val locations = viewModel.locations.value
                if (locations != null) {
                    mediatorLiveData.value = Pair(locations, locationIndex)
                }
            }
            mediatorLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { (locations, locationIndex) ->
                Log.d(TAG, locationIndex.toString())
                Log.d(TAG, locations.size.toString())
                Log.d(TAG, locations[locationIndex].cityName)
                val endOfList = locationIndex >= locations.size - 1
                val startOfList = (locationIndex == 0 && locations.isNotEmpty())
                Log.d(TAG, endOfList.toString())
                Log.d(TAG, startOfList.toString())

                if (endOfList){
                    binding.nextScreenButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                }
                else {
                    binding.nextScreenButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.nextScreenButton.setOnClickListener {
                        viewModel.getSavedLocationWeather()
                        viewModel.incrementIndex()
                    }
                }

                if (startOfList){
                    binding.prevScreenButton.visibility =  View.INVISIBLE
                }
                else {
                    binding.prevScreenButton.visibility =  View.VISIBLE
                    binding.prevScreenButton.setOnClickListener {
                        viewModel.getSavedLocationWeather()
                        viewModel.decrementIndex()
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.currentWeather.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { weatherData -> ...`  observe function is already running in MainDispacher you don't have to run it in extra coroutine